# Getting DIVs to center based upon their parents DIVs?

Tags: video, youtube, embedding

I'm developing a website. I'm creating drop-down lists as menus for the website. I've created hidden divs that appear when you hover over the link in the top menu. However, I can not figure out how to get them to center based upon their parents. I'm assuming it's because they're positioned "absolute," but I don't know how else I could create the hidden DIVs that overlay other stuff without them being absolute. I wouldn't really know what sections of my code to post, so if you want to know what I'm talking about, go to www.theguildwars2hq.com and hover over the links at the top. You'll notice they all start at the left border of the link above them. I'd like them to automatically center around the links, but at the top-offset they're coded. I want them to also automatically be the 100% width of their parents, but every time I try that, it 100%s to another div I'm not even certain of, but I think is "content."

Also, is there a way to make a div automatically create a second column once the div has reached a certain height?

I hope this made some sense, if very little. It's hard to explain my point without having something physical to present and point out.

Comment: Set the parent divs to `position:relative;` This will force children of absolute position to inherit from them instead of continuing to look up the DOM for a non-static element.

Comment: Ah-ha! That fixed my width issue. Thanks so much! However, I'm still having trouble with the centering. For some reason, there's a margin to the left of each drop-down box. I would fix it with just some negative positioning, but unfortunately the spacing is different for each drop-down.

Comment: Actually, after playing around with it for a minute, I discovered it is an even amount of spacing between each one, it just didn't appear to be. However, the problem it presents is that it doesn't stretch the full 100% any more if I have to position it negatively, and just adding padding to one side to accommodate for that would throw off my text-centering.

Comment: I think you'll find that if you actually check the width of the parents (yes including padding and borders) the dropdown are the proper sizes and in the proper places. You need to adjust how you are formatting those parents. Chrome helps immensely if you just pop open the dev tools and select the elements in question.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. I'll have to play around with it a bit, because I have to figure out how to get the drop-downs to work along with the spacing I require to get those borders.